# Strawberries only half red

Tags: strawberries, ripening

Why do my strawberries only grow half red, so the top half is nice and red and the bottom half is white?

If I pick my strawberries like this can I leave them a couple of days near a window so the other half goes red?

How do commercial growers deal with this issue?

If I leave them there until fully ripened I am worried the top half will get spoiled before the back end has time to go red.

My second issue with leaving them to ripen is that they get consumed quickly by other creatures (bird/mice/insect) before I can eat them.

Comment: It would be nice to get a picture.

Answer (score 6):

In order to deal with harmful insects & birds you can **make a scaffold around strawberries and cover them by plastic** or [PEfilm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polyethylene) like [greenhouses](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Greenhouse).

IMO, if you give them time to ripe, keep the temperature between 15-25 ^C and sunlight their color completely will be red.

Edit: more clarified.

Comment: I have had strawberries rot at the top before the end is red.

Comment: I found a nice article about [keeping birds off of your berries](http://organicgardening.about.com/od/fruits/a/birdsberries.htm).

Comment: @jmusser They need more sunlight(at least six hours a day) and consistent moisture (good drainage).